# Merging hundreds excel file with path reference into one pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have probably hundreds or thousands small excel file with bracket into one pandas dataframe

Here's my table of reference `df`

```
    Dataframe_name      Path                                 Sheet
45  finance_auditing    Finance - Accounting/TopSites-Fin... Aggregated_Data_for_Time_Period
46  finance_lending     Finance - Banking/TopSites-...          Aggregated_Data_for_Time_Period
```

What I did

```
finance_auditing  = pd.read_excel('Finance - Accounting/TopSites-Fin... ','Aggregated_Data_for_Time_Period')
finance_lending   = pd.read_excel('Finance - Banking/TopSites-... ','Aggregated_Data_for_Time_Period')
all = finance_auditing.append(finance_lending)
```

The problem is I have hundreds of of file to read and need to append them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to iterate over the pairs of path and sheet and read the corresponding excel file, finally `concat` all the excel files:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet) 
           for path, sheet in zip(df.Path, df.Sheet)])
```

Comment: pd.concat is slow for multiple appends

Comment: @anon01 I'm not sure about the speeds, haven't had a chance to test the speed of `concat`, but I believe here `concat` under the hood uses numpy's  `vstack` to achieve the result, So I believe it shouldn't be that slow compared to doing raw numpy operations.

Comment: I might guess that re-indexing or re-allocation every time the dataframe changes size is cause of additional overhead; not 100% sure

Comment: @anon01 Interesting! Let me have a look at the underlying code for concat.